# Wrong phone number for contacts are shown and called

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, google-contacts, dual-sim

I have a problem with the app 'Contacts' on my Android 7.1 Nougat (Wilefox Swift 2x). In this app both phone numbers from my google account and from whatsapp are synchronized.

- Sometimes the app shows the wrong phone number for a contact. When I call this contact, the person the number belongs to is called instead (always another existing contact). At that time I'm not able to see the correct phone number for the contact. When I try to edit the contact, the phone number is not shown or correct.
- In other situations an incorrect number (number of another contact) is added to a contact. In this case both the correct and the wrong numbers are shown, only the correct number is visible when I try to edit the contact.
- In both cases it says the number is a whatsapp contact. These numbers shouldn't be linked however. I've never done so and I'm not allowed to unlink this.

Recently I removed all contacts and added them manually again. Everytime when adding a new number manually, there was automatically a duplicate added in the contact list from Google Contacts. And again I saw a couple of persons with a number that don't belong to them.

Does anybody know how I can stop this from happening? This is very annoying.

Thanks in advance!

Update: The issue may be caused by a second whatsapp I'm running on this dual sim (in parallel space). Does anyone have more information on how to solve this without removing the second whatsapp?

Comment: Go to Contacts>Settings>Contacts and then mark "Only contacts with phones".

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. I already only show contacts that have a phone number. In some cases the correct number is not visible anymore or the incorrect number is added next to the correct number.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because of WhatsApp. After their latest update (4th Dec) these problems have surged.
Easiest solution is to backup whatsapp and uninstall it. Then reinstall > restore your old chats.

Comment: Maybe this is true.  But I did have to clean them up.  I used an App called Contact Optimizer.